# Python Pyler code not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I have this code for pyler module in python kivy

```
from kivy.app import App

from plyer.notification import notify

class AndroidApp(App):
    def build(self):
        notify('Some title', 'Some message text')

AndroidApp().run()
```

I have installed pyler and kivy from their github repositories, but still I get the following error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "after.py", line 4, in 
    from plyer.notification import notify
ImportError: No module named notification

I'm pretty sure I've installed pyler correctly, and I'm running this app on windows, and according to the docs, pyler notifications is available in windows too. Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notification` is defined as a variable in `plyer/__init__.py`. It is not a module. `import player.notification` won't work. You can use `from plyer import notification` instead.

```
from plyer import notification
notification.notify
```

Comment: Actually, I got this code from a tutorial, [link](https://github.com/inclement/kivycrashcourse/blob/master/video12-using_android_apis/after.py), so isn't it supposed to be correct? Anyway I got it working using your answer, but I'd like to know about that code too, if its some mistake I did or it's not possible in windows.

Comment: i get err with this, `ImportError: cannot import name 'notification' from partially initialized module 'plyer' (most likely due to a circular import)`